# SAPUI5 - sap.m.Input: Will it automatically invoke a soft(virtual)-keyboard if running on the proper device?

Tags: sapui5, virtual-keyboard

As we can see in the manifest file of each SAPUI5 application, there is the array of device-types, which usually has stuff like this inside:

```
    "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
        "icon": "",
        "favIcon": "",
        "phone": "",
        "phone@2": "",
        "tablet": "",
        "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    }
```

I am developing my first SAPUI5 application right now, and I wonder, if the runtime or core somehow knows, when to invoke a virtual keyboard (like on tablets, smartphones and other touchscreen-only devices), and then just simply does it.

Since I am not able to BYOD to test it in my current setup, I wanted to ask in here, if my assumption is right or not.

Comment: what do you mean? UI5 is at the end only a webpage. Every input on any webpage (e.g. just open amazon) opens the keyboard; if an input is focused. Also there are plenty of samples in the www (No need to have BYOD). Just open https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input to play around on any smartphone

Comment: So You mean,  each device will handle it as we all know it.... right?

E.g. visit any webpage with an input field of type numeric  on e.g. android only... will cause the device to popup an softkeyboard. Right ?

Comment: there is also an example about the HTML input types: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputTypes

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it is clarified and Your small but nice idea is helpful.
You can post that as answer. 

The thing to clarify is now:
Is onSubmit or onActiveChange the right event to react on when "i am ready with entering my number "   (no matter which device).....

THOUGH: Type "Number" still opens my standard softkeyboard BUT ignores alpha strokes.,..

Comment: in the ui5 context, you are looking for this event: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase%23events/change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI5 is at the end only a webpage. Every input on any webpage (e.g. just open amazon) opens the keyboard; if the input is focused.

What exactly happened depends heavily on your browser, device, etc.

---

If you are ever in doubt and your company is not allowing BYOD and if there aren't any other touch devices (convertible notebooks) you can at least use the [examples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputTypes) on your private device.

---

Off-topic - If you have a MAC-Book you can also spin up the iphone emulator from xcode and access localhost.